# Extraer texto convertir array string y comparar con otro array eliminando duplicados

Tags: java, array, string, split

estoy leyendo un archivo para extraer cadenas en un array y asi poder compararlo con otra lista y eliminar los duplicados de las 2 listas.
Hice este código pero aunque aparecen iguales en la impresión, no elimina los duplicados.
El archivo1 solo contiene "principio uno dos tres cuatro"(separados por salto de linea y sin comillas.

```
    File archivo1 = new File("Archivo1.txt");
    BufferedInputStream bufferdearchivo1 = new BufferedInputStream(new 
    FileInputStream(archivo1));
    StringBuilder constructorcadena1 = new StringBuilder();
    int byteRead1;
    while ((byteRead1 = bufferdearchivo1.read()) != -1) {
        constructorcadena1.append((char) byteRead1);
    }

    bufferdearchivo1.close();

    String archivoliclas1 = "";
    archivoliclas1 = (constructorcadena1.toString());

    int inicio1 = (archivoliclas1.indexOf("principio"));

    String archivorecortada1 = "";
    archivorecortada1 = (archivoliclas1.substring(inicio1 + 9));

    String[] arraydearchivo1 = archivorecortada1.split("/n");

    for (int h = 0; h < arraydearchivo1.length; h++) {
        System.out.println("Archivo1");
        System.out.println(arraydearchivo1[h]);

    }

    bufferdearchivo1.close();

    String arraydescarte[] = new String[5];

    arraydescarte[0] = "uno";
    arraydescarte[1] = "tres";

    //duplicados
    List<String> listaarchivos2 = Arrays.asList(arraydescarte);

    String[] arrayLimpio = Stream.of(arraydearchivo1).filter(i -> !listaarchivos2.contains(i)).toArray(String[]::new);

    for (int i = 0; i < arrayLimpio.length; i++) {
        System.out.println("Archivos no duplicados");
        System.out.println(arrayLimpio[i]);

    }
```

Comment: Es decir, tienes un fichero con X valores (siempre manteniendo el mismo formato, supongo. Sería importante que fueras más específico en este punto en la pregunta) y una lista con Y valores. Quieres extraer los valores del fichero en un `array`, compararlo con otro ya existente y eliminar duplicados de ambos arrays, ¿no?

Comment: Lo solucioné utilizando BufferedReader en vez de stream, ya que creo que no me permite manipular los datos de la misma forma al compararlos. gracias por responder.

Answer (score 0):

Te recomiendo que eches un vistazo a cómo funcionan los Streams en Java y que te acostumbres a consultar la [API de Java (este enlace es a la versión 8)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/). Es imprescindible que sepas manejar esta herramienta, que te permitirá solucionar la mayoría de dudas sobre la implementación de "lo-que-sea" y que para ejemplos concretos echaras un vistazo a los [Tutoriales](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/index.html).

Para utilizar streams de caracteres es **mucho más práctica** la clase [BufferedReader](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html)

Hace unos días, hiciste una pregunta relativamente similar. Deberías echar un vistazo a las respuestas y aplicar las mismas conclusiones a este problema.

De cualquier manera, te recomiendo que, antes de comenzar a escribir el código, analices el problema y decidas cómo lo vas a abordar. Si son tus primeros proyectos, deberías aplicar escrupulosamente los fundamentos de programación para coger buenas costumbres, para que cuando abordes proyectos más grandes, estés acostumbrado a hacer las cosas "bien hechas". Si no haces un buen análisis, no sabras descomponer el problema en problemas más pequeños (modularización) y si más adelante decides cambiar alguna cosa (como por ejemplo el uso de BufferedInputStream por BufferedReader) no podrás mejorar el código con facilidad (refactorización). Este estudio es **completamente independiente del lenguaje que uses**.

Además, este planteamiento te permitirá "llamar a las cosas por su nombre" y elegir las operaciones a realizar sobre los datos. Al igual que en tu mensaje anterior y conceptualmente hablando, quieres realizar operaciones sobre conjuntos. En este caso, lo que quieres hacer es una **diferencia de conjuntos** (no queda claro si la quieres simétrica o no). Es decir, ya tienes definido tu problema principal.
[Diferencia de conjuntos](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diferencia_de_conjuntos)
[Diferencia simétrica de conjuntos](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diferencia_sim%C3%A9trica)

La segunda parte es desde dónde vienen los datos y en qué formato y cómo los vas a recuperar. Tus datos son fundamentalmente caracteres (aclarar que internamente da igual lo que sea, son flujos de datos; bytes más concretamente) y en tu caso los vas a extraer de un archivo separados por el caracter CR. Si miras BufferedReader, verás que tiene un método readLine que te devuelve una línea completa, descartando el retorno de carro. La reutilización del código es otro de los fundamentos, en este caso de la POO, en el que tú u otro programador ya habeis implementado una solución a un problema que puede usarse en cualquier parte otro programa; así te evitas "redescubrir la rueda". Es fundamental haber aplicado una buena modularización para saber elegir la solución a cada problema.

Una vez tienes los datos, tienes que realizar las operaciones sobre los mismos que *ya has diseñado* de la manera más eficiente posible. **Es aquí donde StackOverflow entra en juego**. Si has hecho un buen análisis y lo has *descompuesto* adecuadamente, puedes explicar concretamente lo que quieres hacer de manera general y apuntar concretamente a la parte de la solución que no funciona; así, en vez de "resolverte el problema" en general, se te puede ayudar con la parte de tu solución que no funciona.

Haz un buen análisis del problema y ve descomponiendo el problema en partes tan pequeñas como sea posible (modularización) así localizaras el problema rápidamente (depuración) y se te podrá ayudar a mejorar el código con más facilidad (refactorización).

Ánimo y un saludo.

https://pearson.es/espa%C3%B1a/TiendaOnline/c%C3%B3mo-programar-en-java-9ed-

Comment: gracias por tus respuestas, Pude solucionarlo y la pagina de las API de java es muy practica al igual que los tutoriales. Gracias otra vez, saludos

Answer (score 0):

Yo cuando elimino duplicados y ya tengo las dos listas (me salto esto porque intuyo que lo haces correctamente) lo que hago es:
-Creo un bucle for para lectura del primer fichero
-Creo otro bucle for para lectura del segundo 
Me refiero a:

```
for(int i=0;i<lista1.length;i++){
   for(int j=0;j<lista.length;j++){
     //codigo usuario

   }
}
```

-Si lista1[i] (la del primer bucle) es igual a lista2[j] (la del segundo bucle) entonces
 continue; (pasas a la siguiente iteración)

-Si cuando terminas el for interno no ha habido duplicado (no se ha salido del bucle) entonces lo metes a array auxiliar.

Sería algo similar a esto (tomandome la libertad de pensar que son strings):

```
for(int i=0;i<lista1.length;i++){
   for(int j=0;j<lista2.length;j++){
     if(lista1[i].equals(lista2[j]){
        continue;
     }
    listaAux.add(lista1[i])
    }

}
   }
}
```